# Go to next iterator in range-based for loop

Tags: c++, for-loop, c++11, iterator, for-range

for my project I need to make the iterators from the loop to go to the next item in the container, do some operations, and return again back to the same iterator and just continue, however, for some reason neither `advance` nor `next` and then using `prev` seem to work. So how could I get the next iterator and just return to prev one?

I get the following error message :

```
no matching function for call to 'next(int&)'
no type named 'difference_type' in 'struct std::iterator_traits<int>'
```

Thank you!

```
template<class T>
void insert_differences(T& container)
{

    for(auto it : container){
        // do some operations here
        //advance(it,1);
        it = next(it); 
        // do some operations here 
        //advance(it, -1);
        it = prev(it);
        }

}
```

Comment: The problem is that [the range-for statement](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) iterates over *values* in the container. The variable `it` in your case is a *value* from the container, not an iterator. And there's no way to get an iterator from a value. If you need to use actual iterators, then you should create such a loop explicitly (the "normal" `for` loop) using actual iterators.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Range-based for loop](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) iterates over elements. The name `it` is confusing here; it's not iterator but element, that's why `std::next` and `std::prev` don't work with it.

> Executes a for loop over a range.
>
> Used as a more readable equivalent to the traditional for loop
>   operating over a range of values, such as all elements in a container.

You have to write the loop using iterators by yourself like

```
for(auto it = std::begin(container); it != std::end(container); it++){
    // do some operations here
    //advance(it,1);
    it = next(it); 
    // do some operations here 
    //advance(it, -1);
    it = prev(it);
}
```

Comment: As an alternative, if the iterator isn't used after the `it = prev(it)` assignment, then one could skip that *and* skip the `it++` in the loop.